# Pane Buccellato de Lucca

Tags: baking

Has anyone tried baking the buccellato de Lucca? I'm looking forward to find the original recipe from Lucca. You can find several recipes over the internet, in italian, which I can more or less understand, but I'm interested to check if someone knows the real deal (eg. travels to Italy often or has family from Italy).

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

As the origins of the **Buccellato di Lucca** go back to the 15th century, you can be fairly sure that there is not "the one and only canonical recipe".

The *[Italian Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buccellato_di_Lucca)* states:

> Il Buccellato di Lucca non ha una ricetta riconosciuta, come accade spesso per i dolci appartenenti ad una tradizione locale, e ogni forno e pasticceria ritiene di custodirne il segreto per una perfetta riuscita.

Which roughly translates to "there is no officially recognized recipe, [...] every bakery keeps their secret of the perfect recipe.".

And I suppose the same is true for every family, who sees their recipe, probably handed down over generations, as the right one.

As recipe requests are generally off topic here (partly because we don't want to put ourselves in the line of fire between Italian *nonne* defending the family recipe for Buccellato), your approach of reading a few recipes and choosing one or a combination thereof is the best solution.